# How to make NSTableView cells un-selectable, but still have NStextField in the cells editable

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I am using a view based NSTableview. Now that view has an instance of NSTextField which i want to be selectable.
But the rows of the table view should not be selectable(This is done using the delegate method - tableView:shouldSelectRow: which always returns 'NO'.)

I am able to copy text from textField only when i make the table rows selectable as well. Is there any way to keep only the NSTextField selectable without making the table rows selectable too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this code in your awakeFromNib method or where ever it is applicable to your code. Your NSTableView will be not selectable, but your text fields will be editable.

```
[myTableView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone];
```

Comment: Attention: That may cause problems with context menus (rectangle is not correctly shown if row is selected).

You should use the :shouldSelectItem delegate method.

Comment: I did say to put it where ever it is applicable in your code. In your case, if the :shouldSelectItem delegate works, then use it. cheers.